# How can I prove this proposition from Peano Axioms: (Cancellation law). Let a, b, c be natural numbers such that a + b = a + c. Then we have b = c.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, axioms, peano-axioms

> **Peano Axioms.**
>
> **Axiom 2.1**
>
> $0$ is a natural number.
>
> **Axiom 2.2**
>
> If $n$ is a natural number then $n++$ is also a natural number. (Here $n++$
>   denotes the successor of $n$ and previously in the book the notational
>   implication has been bijected to the familiar $1,2…$).
>
> **Axiom 2.3**
>
> $0$ is not the successor of natural number; i.e. we have $n++≠0$ for every
>   natural number $n$.
>
> **Axiom 2.4**
>
> Different natural numbers must have different successors; i.e., if $n,m$
>   are natural numbers and $n≠m$, then $n++≠m++$.
>
> **Axiom 2.5**
>
> Let $P(n)$ be any property pertaining to a natural number $n$. Suppose
>   that $P(0)$ is true, and suppose that whenever $P(n)$ is true, $P(n++)$ is
>   also true. Then $P(n)$ is true for every natural number $n$.
>
> **Definition of Addition:** Let m be a natural number. We define, $0+m=m$
>   and suppose we have inductively defined the addtion $n+m$ then we
>   define, $(n++)+m=(n+m)++$. Where $n++$ is the successor of $n$.

Terence Tao has a proof in his Analysis I book, but I couldn't understand . I want a proof line by line like this:

*Thm: 3 is a natural number* 
\begin{align*}
   & 0 \text{ is natural } && \text{Axiom 2.1 }\\
   & 0++ = 1 \text{ is natural } && \text{Axiom 2.2}\\
   & 1++ = 2 \text{ is natural } && \text{Axiom 2.2}\\
   & 2++ = 3 \text{ is natural } && \text{Axiom 2.2}
   \end{align*}

Comment: What have you proven so far? Have you shown commutativity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proof is by induction on $a$.

*Basis* [case with $a=0$]. We want to prove that :

> if $0+b=0+c$, then $b=c$.

But we have that : $0+b=b$, by definition of *addition*.

And also : $0+c=c$.

Thus, by [transitivity of *equality*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Equality_and_its_axioms) : $b=c$.

---

*Induction step*. Assume that the property holds for $a$ and prove it for $a'$ [I prefer to use $a'$ instead of $a++$ for the *successor* of $a$].

This means :

> assume that "if $a+b=a+c$, then $b=c$" holds, and prove that "if $a'+b=a'+c$, then $b=c$" holds.

We have $a'+b=(a+b)'$ by definition of *addition*.

And $a'+c=(a+c)’$, by definition of *addition*.

We assume that : $a'+b=a'+c$, and thus, again by transitivity of equality, we have that : $(a+b)'=(a+c)'$.

By axiom 2.4 (different numbers have different successors), by contraposition, we conclude that $(a+b)=(a+c)$.

Thus, applying induction hypothesis, we have that :

> $b=c$.

---

---

The general strategy used above in order to prove "if $P$, then $Q$", is to assume $P$ and derive $Q$.

This type of proof is called [Conditional Proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_proof); we can see it above :

1) if $a+b=a+c$, then $b=c$ --- induction hypothesis

2) $a'+b=a'+c$ --- assumption for CP

3) $(a+b)'=(a+c)'$ --- from 2) and definition of addition and tarnsitivity of equality

4) $a+b=a+c$ --- from 3) and axiom 2.4 by [Contraposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition) [the axiom says : "if $(a+b \ne a+c)$, then $(a+b)' \ne (a+c)'$"; thus, contraposing it we get : "if $(a+b)' = (a+c)'$, then $(a+b) = (a+c)$"] and Modus ponens

5) $b=c$ --- from 4) and 1) by [Modus ponens (also called : detachment)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_ponens)

> 6) if $a'+b=a'+c$, then $b=c$ --- from 2) and 5) by Conditional Proof.

Comment: (In your last yellow box before the general strategy, it should be $b=c$)

Comment: Thanks! Amazing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a formal proof done in Fitch:

(Note: I use $s(x)$ instead of $x$++)

[image]